# File Scanner hangs indefinetely

Tags: java

Attempting to make a program which reads a file containg celphone numbers and costs per month, and outputs the numbers and costs that are below a user-inputted threshhold. However, when running, the file hangs indefinetely after user input of the threshold.

The code looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class exam1
{
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
{


    Scanner G = new Scanner (System.in);
    ArrayList<String> cellNum = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Float> cost = new ArrayList<Float>();
    String filename = "";
    int i=0, b=0;
    float thresh = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter filename: ");
    filename = G.next();
    File file = new File (filename);
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner (file);
    System.out.print("\nEnter Cell Bill Threshold: ");
    thresh = G.nextFloat();

    while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
    {
        b++;
    }
    fileInput.close();

    while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
    {
        for (i=0; i < b; i++)
        {
            cellNum.add(fileInput.next());
            cost.add(fileInput.nextFloat());
        }
        fileInput.close();
    }

    for (i=0; i<cost.size();i++)
    {
        if (cost.get(i) > thresh )
        {
            cellNum.remove(i);
            cost.remove(i);

        }
    }

    System.out.print("\nBills exceeding threshold: ");
    System.out.printf("\n%12s%8s", "Number", "Amount");

    for (i=0; i<cost.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%12s%8.2f", cellNum.get(i), cost.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

the file in question thats being read looks like this:

```
403-222-1023 37.24
403-983-1942 46.44
403-982-1952 50.35
```

I feel like I'm mising something incredibly obvious but any help would be apprecated here. Thank you for your time, and sorry to bother you.

Comment: That 'obvious' thing you're missing is that you're closing the file inside the red loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this loop:

```
while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
{
    b++;
}
```

You never consume the next line in `fileInput` so `hasNextLine()` will always return true, resulting in an infinite loop. You need to call `nextLine()` within the while loop, so that `hasNextLine()` will at some point return false.

---

Also then you do:

```
fileInput.close();

while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
    //...
    fileInput.close();
}
```

You cannot close a source and then try to read from it. Only close the `Scanner` after you are completely done reading from it.

If you are sure that each line will be in the specified format you can just do:

```
while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
{
      cellNum.add(fileInput.next());
      cost.add(fileInput.nextFloat());      
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved it. However, I realize my output is wrong. No matter what I put for the threshold when running the program, it only returns the second line of the input file.

Comment: @LeviFM There were a few formatting problems when I ran it (You have no newline so all the print statements are on one line) but other than that it produced the correct output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on `while` loop

```
 while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
    {
        b++;
    }
```

`fileInput.hasNextLine()` will always return true because you never read the line and you will forever be on first line.